# Show that if $\bar{A} \cap \bar {B} \subseteq C$ then $A \cup B \cup C$ is the universal set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For any subset $A$ of the universe $U$, we denote $\bar{A}$ as $U - A$.

Show that for any subsets $A, B, C$ of the universe $U$, if $\bar{A} \cap \bar {B} \subseteq C$ then $A \cup B \cup C = U$.

Additionally, prove or disprove the converse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the forward direction, consider any element $x\in U$. Then, either $x\in A$, $x\in B$, or $x\in\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}$. In the last scenario, because we have $\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}\subset C$, it must be that $x\in C$. Thus, $x\in A\cup B\cup C$, giving us $U\subset A\cup B\cup C$. The reverse inclusion $U\supset A\cup B\cup C$ is automatic, so we indeed have $U= A\cup B\cup C$.

For the reverse direction, suppose we have $U= A\cup B\cup C$. If $\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}$ is empty, then $\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}\subset C$ is trivial. Else, consider any $x$ in $\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}$. Because $x$ is in $U$, we must have $x$ is in $A\cup B\cup C$. As $x\in\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}$, we infer that $x\not\in A$ and $x\not\in B$, meaning $x\in C$. This gives $\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}\subset C$.

Comment: Do you mean that if $x \in \bar{A} \cap \bar {B}$ then $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$ and therefore $x \in C$?

Comment: the question has not 2 direction

Comment: and I think the answer is not correct (first paragraph)

Comment: @user1 Please back up your allegations.

Comment: @user214441 Yes, I changed the wording slightly for added clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that since $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}\subseteq C$ then $\overline{(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})}\supseteq   \overline{C}$. We have  $A \cup B \cup C = \overline{(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})}\cup C\supseteq\overline{C}\cup C=\mathcal{U}.$

Reverse:

$\mathcal{U}=A \cup B \cup C\Rightarrow\,\,\emptyset= \overline{\mathcal{U}} = (\overline{A\cup B})\cap\overline{C}=(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})\cap\overline{C}\Rightarrow (\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})\subseteq C.$

Answer (score 1):

by [*De Morgan's laws*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) :
$$ \overline {  A\cup B}=\bar{A} \cap \bar {B} \subseteq C$$ 
so $$U- (A \cup B)\subseteq C$$ 
hence
 $$U\subset A \cup B \cup C $$
therefore
$$A \cup B \cup C = U $$